# AMPL "Locking" a derived variable to a value

Tags: ampl

I want to investigate whether it is profitable to invest in an additional production facility, and hence I have to account for an capitilization in my objective function.

As such I am wondering if it is possible to, say, if y[t] = 1, then y[g] = 1
for g != t, g > t and where g,t is a subset of the time interval set T.

My first thought was to have:

```
subject to Constraint1:
    y[t] = y[t-1] for all t in T
```

But that must surely render the solution of y to become the start value in y[0] which is something I obviously do not want.

For clarification. Assume that y[t] is a binary variable whose value is 1 if the investment is undertaken in time t, otherwise 0.

Hope anyone can shed some light into this!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint `y[t] = 1, then y[g] = 1 for g != t, g > t` can be represented in AMPL as something like:

```
s.t. c{t in T: t != t0}: y[t + 1] >= y[t];
```

where `t0` is the first element of set `T`. Note the use of `>=` instead of `=`. If `y[t]` is 1 for some `t`, it will drive `y` for all subsequent values of `t` to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My model is now working properly!